# How can I make SVG clip path animation compatible in Firefox

Tags: firefox, animation, svg, cross-browser, clip-path

I have managed to create an SVG animation using an SVG clip path and CSS that works correctly in Google Chrome, Opera and Safari. However, in Firefox, the SVG is clipped but none of the CSS code for the animation seems to be applied.

On other browsers, there is an inital delay of three seconds and then the clip path scales up to gradually reveal the entire image. Does anyone know why I cannot get this code to work on Firefox?

Alternatively, is there any way to ensure that the whole image is displayed in browsers that do not support the animation?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
img, svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#carClip {
-ms-transform: scale(0.5) translate(1950px,380px); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(0.5) translate(1950px,380px); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: scale(0.5) translate(1950px,380px); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: scale(0.5) translate(1950px,380px); /* Firefox */
transform: scale(0.5) translate(1950px,380px);
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: rgb(108,110,112);
}

.clip-shape {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
  -o-transform: scale(0.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
  transform: scale(0.5);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%; 
  -moz-transform-origin: center center; 
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%; 
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%; 
  transform-origin: center center;  
  -webkit-animation: scale 18s forwards 1;
  -moz-animation: scale 18s forwards 1;
  -o-animation: scale 18s forwards 1;
  -ms-animation: scale 18s forwards 1;
  animation: scale 18s forwards 1;  
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
  -o-animation-delay: 3s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale {
  0% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.5); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: scale(11); }
}

@-o-keyframes scale {
  0% { -o-transform: scale(0.5); }
  100% { -o-transform: scale(11); }
}

@-moz-keyframes scale {
  0% { -moz-transform: scale(0.5); }
  100% { -moz-transform: scale(11); }
}

@-ms-keyframes scale {
  0% { -ms-transform: scale(0.5); }
  100% { -ms-transform: scale(11); }
}

@keyframes scale {
  0% { transform: scale(0.5); }
  100% { transform: scale(11); }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 1809 692">
 <defs>
    <clipPath id="carClip">
    <polygon class="clip-shape" fill="none" id="thePath" points="174 75 542 0 669 363 396 546 0 324 174 75"></polygon>
      </clipPath>
 </defs>
 <image clip-path="url(#carClip)" width="1809" height="692" xlink:href="http://dev.lexuspreciousmetal.tsadvertising.co.uk/wp-content/themes/lexus/images/banner.png" ></image>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS animation does not work in Firefox when used in clipPaths you could use SMIL instead to do this which will work in Chrome, Opera and Safari too.

Comment: Thank you. Could you suggest any resources that I could look at to achieve the same animation using SMIL please? I'm not sure how I would be able to control the starting position, for example, using this method.

Comment: Try it and let me see where you're stuck. There are examples here: https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#multi-valued_animation

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have added this code inbetween the polygon tags:

<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="scale" 
 dur="18s" values="1;11" repeatCount="0" fill="freeze" begin="3s"/> and added this code to the clipPath tag: transform="translate(1065,250), scale(0.3)"

but I cannot get the shape to scale properly to reveal the whole image like it does in other browsers with my previous code. Is there an attribute I am missing?